# Any way of telling if a dependency property is being subscribed to?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have a custom control with a dependency property that is fairly expensive to compute. Therefore I don't want to do so unless someone is actually interested in it.

Does WPF supply any way of seeing if anything is looking at a dependency property?

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to stop a Binding to a DP from taking effect (i.e. before performing your expensive computation), and that is the Validation callback ...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx#Validation_Callbacks.